# ambiguity concerning the fundamental group of the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\alpha(s)$ be the loop in $S^1$ starts from $1$ and goes to $-1$ and back along the upper hemisphere and let $\beta(s)$ be the loop that goes from $1$ to $-1$ and back along the lower hemisphere. Since both loops are not surjective they are null-homotopic so that their product is null-homotopic as well.

However, we can interpret the product $\alpha(s)\cdot \beta(s)$ in the following way:
We let $h(s)$ be the path from $1$ to $-1$ along the upper hemisphere and then we go around the a full circle starting and ending at $-1$ and denote this by $\gamma(s)$ (note that $\gamma(s)$ is not null-homotopic). Then we go back from $-1$ to $1$ along the lower hemisphere and denote this $g(s)$.

But this defines and isomorphism of loops between  the fundamental groups based at $1$ and $-1$ i.e. $H(\gamma)= [h\cdot \gamma \cdot h^{-1}]=  [h\cdot] [\gamma][ \cdot h^{-1}]$. But since $g(s)$ homotopic to $h^{-1}(s)$ (since they are both null-homotopic) it follows that $H(\gamma)\neq 0$.

So, we conclude that $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is null homotopic and not null-homotopic and this where I am confused.

Comment: Why are $g$ and $h^{-1}$ null-homotopic here? Only $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are null-homotopic. In particular, how do you conclude that $g$ and $h^{-1}$ are homotopic?

Comment: because they are not surjective they are null-homotopic and by the transitivity of the homotopy equivalence relation they must be homotopic to each other.

Comment: Of course, my mistake.

Comment: Isn't $H(\gamma) = [h]*[\gamma]*[h^{-1}] = [h]*[\gamma]*[g] = 0$ since $h*\gamma*g$ is path-homotopic to the constant path at $1$.

Comment: but $\gamma$ is not null-homotopic in the fundamental group based at -1 so the group isomorphism can't map non-zero elements in one group to a zero element in the other.

Comment: It is an isomorphism so it can't be trivial

Comment: I am still not convinced that $h$ and $g$ are homotopic. Because if they were, then $[h*g]$ would be trivial, which is clearly not the case. But $S^1$ is path-connected, so they should be homotopic given that they are both null-homotopic.

Comment: technically both $h$ and $g$ are not closed loops so they do not belong in the fundamental group of either point.

Comment: I am just following the definition of Hatchers Book where he defines the isomorphism in the above way where the product is defined for paths taking one base point  to another base point and they do not have to belong in the fundamental group of either point.

Comment: The issue here is that $[h]*[\gamma]*[h^{-1}] \neq [h]*[\gamma]*[g]$ because $[h^{-1}] \neq [g]$. They are homotopic, but they are not equal as elements in the fundamental group since they are not even elements in the fundamental group.

Comment: $[\gamma] \mapsto [h]*[\gamma]*[h^{-1}]$ is a well-defined group isomorphism, but we cannot simply replace $[h^{-1}]$ with $[g]$ just because $h^{-1}$ and $g$ are homotopic. An example in which we can make a replacement would be something like $[\gamma] * [\overline{\gamma}] * [\beta] = [\beta]$ because $\gamma * \overline{\gamma}$ is a loop that is path-homotopic to the constant loop.

Comment: it is proven by Hatcher (I believe) that the path product is independent of coset or homotopy class representation otherwise the product would not make sense. The product of paths is well defined even if they are not closed because they form a gropoid and only in the case of closed loops does the product defines a group.

Comment: Gosh my algebraic topology is so rusty, but I think I see the problem.

In the context of the isomorphism $H$, $[h^{-1}]$ denotes the PATH-homotopy class of $h^{-1}$. Yes $h^{-1}$ and $g$ are homotopic, but they are not PATH-homotopic. The homotopy between them does not fix the endpoints (this is obvious because $h^{-1}$ cannot be path-homotopic to a constant function since its endpoints are not equal). Thus, we cannot not conclude $[h^{-1}] = [g]$.

Comment: the endpoints are fixed at -1 and 1.

Comment: Yes $h^{-1}$ and $g$ have the same endpoints, but a path-homotopy between them must fix the endpoints throughout the entire deformation. This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with this argument:

1. $h$ and $g$ are not loops, but paths, so one cannot do loop-equivalence-classes calculations with them;
2. $h$ and $g^{-1}$ are not the same function.

(If one allows homotopies of paths that don't fix the far endpoint, then *every* path from a given basepoint is homotopic to every other.)

Answer (score 0):

Since my comments were all over the place and wildly incorrect, I will give a better answer here.

In the context of the isomorphism $H$, $[h^{-1}]$ denotes the PATH-homotopy class of $h^{-1}$. While it is true that $h^{-1}$ and $g$ are homotopic, they are not PATH-homotopic. This because the homotopy from $h^{-1}$ to $g$ does not fix the endpoints throughout the entire deformation. This is obvious because the homotopy from $h^{-1}$ to some constant map cannot possible be a path-homotopy since no constant path shares endpoints with $h^{-1}$. Thus, $[h^{-1}] \neq [g]$.